# How can I import a tab delimited text file with Import-CSV when the file has no header row?

Tags: powershell

I have a huge text file (around 500 MB) that is tab delimited. It doesn't contain headers. So it looks like:

```
20140711   IBM   29.9068    tom.smith@ibm.com    this is interesting
20140712   HP   2.3000    tom.smith@ibm.com    this is interesting
20140713   GOOGLE   44.9033    tom.smith@ibm.com    this is interesting
20140714   HTC   739.70    tom.smith@ibm.com    this is interesting
20140715   SAMSUNG   8.442    tom.smith@ibm.com    this is interesting
20140716   MICROSOFT   67.104    tom.smith@ibm.com    this is interesting
20140717   DELL   5.0823    tom.smith@ibm.com    this is interesting
...
...
...
```

I need to use Powershell to load the text into the SQL Server database as a table. As there is no headers in the text file, the "Import-Csv" cmdlet output the content incorrectly. I think it always treats the first line as headers.

How can "Import-Csv" output whatever in the text file and forget about header config?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the `-header` switch for `import-csv`?

Comment: Not yet. How does that work?

Comment: `help -full import-csv` ;-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try this :

```
$data = Import-Csv C:\temp\F.csv -Header "date","company","value","mail","description" -Delimiter "`t"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$header3 = @("Column_1","Column_2","Column_3","Column_4","Column_5")        

$data = Import-Csv $filePath -Header $header3 -Delimiter "`t"
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a huge file, may I suggest to use "-Raw' option.

Something like:

```powershell
$header= "Date   EventLog   EntryType"
(get-content -Raw $File) | foreach-object {$_ -replace "^", "$header`n"} | set-content  $File
```

Kind regards